# How to write method to csv not just string? Ruby csv gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, parsing, methods

I need to put the text content from an html element to a csv file. With the ruby csv gem, it seems that the primary write method for wrapped Strings and IOs only converts a string even if an object is specified.

For example:

```
 Searchresults = puts browser.divs(class: 'results_row').map(&:text)
 csv << %w(Searchresults)
```

returns only "searchresults" in the csv file.

It seems like there should be a way to specify the text from the div element to be put and not just a literal string.

Edit:

Okay arieljuod and spickermann were right. Now I am getting text content from the div element output to the csv, but not all of it like when I output to the console. The div element "results_row" has two a elements with text content. It also has a child div "results_subrow" with a paragraph of text content that is not getting written to the csv.
HTML:

```
<div class="bodytag" style="padding-bottom:30px; overflow:visible"> 
<h2>Search Results for "serialnum3"</h2>
<div id="results_banner">
    Products
    <span>Showing 1 to 2 of 2 results</span>
</div>
<div class="pg_dir"></div>
<div class="results_row">
    <a href="/products/fuji/" title="Fuji, Inc.">FUJI</a>
    <a href="/products/fuji/50mm lens/" title="Fuji, Inc.">50mm lens</a>
    <div class="results_subrow">
        <p>more product info</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="results_row">
    <a href="/products/fuji/" title="Fuji, Inc. 2">FUJI</a>
    <a href="/products/fuji/50mm lens/" title="Fuji, Inc.">50mm lens</a>
    <div class="results_subrow">
        <p>more product info 2</p>  
    </div>
</div>
<div class="pg_dir"></div>
```

My code:

```
 search_results = browser.divs(class: 'results_row').map(&:text)
 csv << search_results
```

I'm thinking that including the child div "results_subrow" in the locator will find what I am missing. Like:

```
search_results = browser.divs(class: 'results_row', 'results_subrow').map(&:text)
 csv << search_results
```

Comment: don't use capital S on the variable, and remove the `%w(..)` and the `puts`, you are mixing a lot of things there

Comment: ok yeah I didn't mean to include puts thank you

Comment: ok so it is now successfully writing to the csv. But outputing to the console gets all the text content in the div element and writing to the csv gets only the first title. Is there a way to work around this?

Answer (score 1):

`%w[Searchresults]` creates an array containing the word `Searchresults`. You probably want something like this:

```
# assign the array returned from `map` to the `search_results` variable
search_results = browser.divs(class: 'results_row').map(&:text)

# output the `search_results`. Note that the return value of `puts` is `nil`
# therefore something like `Searchresults = puts browser...` doesn't work
puts search_results

# append `search_results` to your csv 
csv << search_results
```

Comment: This works but the text from the div element contains commas and there's text from different child elements in the div that is not being appended to the csv.

Comment: put to the console gets all the text content. Writing to the csv gets only the first title. The array format must be interrupted by commas in the text content

Comment: You might want to add examples of what `browser.divs(class: 'results_row').map(&:text)` returns and what you want to add to your CSV instead to your question.